# Do pushdown parsers scan tokens or single characters?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, pushdown-automaton

I am currently a bit confused about what kind of input pushdown automations excpect. I know the concept behind them (transitions, states, stacks, symbols, popping etc) but I dont really understand what:

A) The alphabet is for if we need all characters from a-z and 0-9 since we are parsing tokens not individual characters such as the typical 101 or ABAB examples.

B) Does the pushdown even accept tokens. For example: if the token "TOK_IF" is found then go to next transition or state.

Could you enlighten me about points A and B? Im really confused.

Comment: *Any* parser processes tokens, whether pushdown, top-down, bottom-up, LL, LR, RL, RR, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (deterministic) pushdown-automaton can be used to parse a (deterministic) context-free language.
It is possible to define the grammar of this language over single characters, which make up the text to parse. This however needs a vast amount of states.

Hence, it is more efficient (and easier to formulate and comprehend the grammar) to *pre-parse keywords and identifiers to tokens* (usually by a *lexer*) and treat these tokens as a single entity. Lexers can be implemented much faster than using the pushdown-automaton and a large number of states to do the same job.

Comment: But is it more like: while (token = pda.getNextToken()) pda.evaluate(token) and depending on what token it is i change state etc.

Comment: Or is it more like all tokens are treated as 1 input : pda.evaluate(IF COND EXP + EXP)

Comment: No, the tokens are read one after another (often with a lookahead on the next token, depending on the exact type of the parser) and change the state accordingly.

Comment: So is it more like my first example with the while loop right? I understand. But your answer is nearly perfect. Could you explain a bit more why all the fuss about the alphabet when reading pda theory? Its just used when treating chars of a word?

Comment: I mean the alphabet is pretty useless to me when using tokens instead of wanting to parse every letter.

Comment: Yes, more like the loop. Usually, the lexer parses the input into tokens with supplementary information, for example, an identifier is matched with a certain regular expression, the token's name is `TOK_ID` or similar, and the supplementary information is the name of the identifier. Or a number, where the token is `TOK_NUM` and the information is the number itself, etc.